# Why does the addition of two float numbers is incorrect in C?

Tags: c, floating-point

I have a problem with the addition of two float numbers. 
Code below:

```
float a = 30000.0f;
float b = 4499722832.0f;

printf("%f\n", a+b);
```

Why the output result is 450002816.000000? (The correct one should be 450002832.)

Comment: think you meant to say b= 449972832.0f

Comment: `float`s aren't precise enough to hold all the digits in a number as large as `b`. Use `double` or `long double` instead.

Comment: See the question http://stackoverflow.com/q/2386772/643383

Comment: Also turn on all compiler warnings, a good compiler should have warned you about that.

Comment: Downvoted, this is a trivially searchable FAQ.

Comment: 30,000 + 4,499,722,832 = 4,499,752,832

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point inaccuracy examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Float are not represented exactly in C - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision, so calculations with float can only give an approximate result.

This is especially apparent for larger values, since the possible difference can be represented as a percentage of the value. In case of adding/subtracting two values, you get the worse precision of both (and of the result).

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with C per se - floating point numbers in general can't exactly represent every number within their range.  It's inherent to the whole idea of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Floating-point values cannot represent all integer values.

Remember that single-precision floating-point numbers only have 24 (or 23, depending on how you count) bits of precision (i.e. significant figures).  So as values get larger, you begin to lose low-end precision, which is why the result of your calculation isn't quite "correct".

Answer (score 2):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#IEEE_754%3a_floating_point_in_modern_computers)

> Single precision, called "float" in the C language family, and "real" or "real*4" in Fortran. This is a binary format that occupies 32 bits (4 bytes) and its significand has a precision of 24 bits (**about 7 decimal digits**).

So your number doesn't actually fit in `float`. You can use `double` instead.

Comment: Right - note that in this case, the answer *is* correct to 7 decimal places.

Comment: In fact, you should pretty much never use `float` unless for some reason memory is _really_ tight. Use `double` unless you have a strong reason not to.

Comment: Or if you know your values don't get too high or too low. Like I myself always use `float`s in writing graphics code.