# How to insert/bind a float datatype value in a sqlite3 database

Tags: iphone, ios4, sqlite

I was able to insert and retrieve integer, text datatype in my sqlite3 database. Can you please guide me how to do the same for a float datatype for my iPhone app.

Comment: I would suggest you to either quote your answer here or remove the question to prevent unanswered questions on SO.

Comment: sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 7, [[person  valueForKey:@"salary"] floatValue]);

Comment: I am adding it in comment as I am not able to answer my own question

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, 7, [[person valueForKey:@"salary"] floatValue]);
```

http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

[Difference between float and double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double)