# C code not running as expected

Tags: c

I wrote a simple c program to find square roots of 2,3,4,5 using newton-raphson iteration technique. This code runs to find and display square root of 2 only. Afterwards it hangs. I could not figure out the problem with this code:

```
# include<stdio.h>

    float square(float x);
    float absolutevalue(float x);

int main(void)
{
    printf("square root of 2 is %f\n", square(2));
    printf("square root of 3 is %f\n", square(3));
    printf("square root of 4 is %f\n", square(4));
    printf("square root of 5 is %f\n", square(5));

    return 0;
}

float square(float x)
{
    float epsilon = 0.0000001;
    float guess = 1;

    while (absolutevalue(guess*guess - x) >= epsilon)
        guess = ((x/guess) + guess) / 2;

    return guess;
}

float absolutevalue(float x)
{
    if (x < 0)
        x = -x;

    return x;
}
```

Comment: `square` is a reserved identifier when used with external linkage

Comment: Your epsilon is too small, the float type doesn't have enough significant digits.  Replace all float by *double* for a quick fix.

Comment: Looking at the [output here](http://stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a9548fc448972258896a9e17cb43e8a5), printing the value of `guess` in the loop, you can see the problem quite easily.

Comment: @HansPassant post it as answer...

Comment: @Hans Passant increasing the size of epsilon worked.. yet it is not clear to me why it was hanging earlier? could you explain a bit more?

Comment: probably because you entered a land known as Undefined Behavior

Comment: @user1825355 - Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double

Comment: SO is not for code review, so your question (what question) is not really appropriate, here.

Comment: @JensGustedt: The OP asked a specific question, namely why the code was hanging right after seeing the square root of 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything will work fine if you replace `float` with `double` everywhere.