# Strange behavior when compiler converts from float to double

Tags: arduino

I have an array:

```
float foo[3];
```

In the ino file I have to send one of them to the PID as input.

```
double output;
PID myPID(&input, &output, &target, 1, 0.0, 1.1, DIRECT);
...
void loop(){
  input =foo[2];   
  myPID.Compute();
  Serial.print(output); //output: "nan"
...
}
```

The PID is as follow:

```
PID::PID(double* Input, double* Output, double* Setpoint,
        double Kp, double Ki, double Kd, int ControllerDirection)
```

It compiles but the output of the PID outvalue is nan.

However if I set the input to -1.2 then it works.

```
void loop(){
      input =foo[2];  
      input = -1.2;
      myPID.Compute();
      Serial.print(output); //output: "1200"
    ...
    }
```

How can I fix this? The compiler should auto convert double the float. As in Mega 2560.
I have also tried: `input =double(foo[2]);` without any success.

---

EDIT:

```
  Serial.print(foo[2]);  //Prints -9.2
  foo[2] = -9.2;         // I manually set foo[2] to -9.2  
  xAngle = foo[2];
  xPID.Compute();        //Computes perfectly.
```

I have to add that foo is in a custom library. This is so strange. Anyone got a clue about this?

Comment: A little more code would help.  Is foo[2] initialized?  I'm not sure it's zeroed like it would be in C or C++.  If it's a NAN to be begin with, and a calc is made with it, the result should be a NAN.

Comment: Which PID library are you using?

Comment: Arduino PID Library - Version 1.0.1 by Brett Beauregard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, all AVR doubles are floats as [described here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc) or [here](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Double). This makes doubles be the same as floats on Arduino Mega 2560.  You can verify this by comparing `sizeof(double);` and `sizeof(float);` both will return `4`.
- Secondly, if you want to cast one type to another the syntax is `(targetType)sourceType`, so if you do that sort of a thing, your assignment should look like this

  ```
  input =(double)foo[2];
  ```

or

```
    input =(double)(foo[2]);
```

However, this is irrelevant in this case since doubles and floats are identical.

I think most likely the problem comes from the fact that your PID controller does not like whatever value you have in `foo[2]` given the parameters you set.  Have you tried `foo[2]=-1.2` before assigning `input = foo[2];`?

Comment: You are right. Setting foo[2]=val works fine. val is the identical float from foo[2]. It just doesnt make any sense to me. I updated the question please look if you got the time.

Comment: I fixed it by just recreating foo as a double.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. If you don't have the `foo[2] = -9.2;` in the code above then `PID.Compute()` fails?  Where is your `float foo[3];` declared exactly?