# Convert a string to float in Objective C without rounding it.?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, string

How can i convert a string to float in Objective C without rounding it.?

I tried to convert a string 8.56021285234;

```
float result=[string floatValue];
```

giving 8.560213, the rounded value.

How can i avoid this? How i can get the exact value?

Comment: could you try: double result=[string doubleValue];

Comment: Using double also i get only upto 6 decimal points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're using a float. A float can usually only hold around 7-digits max. A double can hold many more digits. A float is 32-bit while a double is 64-bit therefore giving it "double" the precision. A simple work-around to your problem would be to do:

`double result = [string doubleValue];`

When logging, make sure to use `NSLog(@"%.12f",result);` to show the entire double as %f defaults to only a 6 decimal precision.

Comment: NSString *value = @"8.44654656565"; double dblValue = [value doubleValue]; NSLog(@"%f",dblValue); logging value 8.446547

Comment: @Nitin Your error is in the formatting in your log. %f defaults to only to a 6 decimal precision. Use `NSLog(@"%.11f",dblValue);` to see the whole thing in the log. I have revised my answer.

Comment: :I want the string to convert in to exact float value. Because i need to use this later in the execution of my code. If i use %.11f i can log the value correctly. But still in my variable its only 6 decimal places

Comment: @Nitin The string is converting to an exact value. When I do the following code: 

`NSString *value = @"8.123456789";`
`double dblValue = [value doubleValue];`
`double newDbl = dblValue * 3;`
`NSLog(@"%.9f", newDbl);`

The log returns 24.370370367. That kind of decimal precision would only be possible if the string converted exactly.

Comment: Yea thanks man. I mistook that the result will be only 6 decimal places. Thanks for understanding me that.

Answer (score 4):

You can't put more than about 7 digits of precision in a float.  You need a type with more precision, like double, see here:

[Difference between float and double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double)

Comment: NSString *value = @"8.44654656565"; double dblValue = [value doubleValue]; NSLog(@"%f",dblValue); logging value 8.446547

Comment: This is the %10f thing, See @Greg's response above

Answer (score 3):

Try double instead of float:

```
NSString *val = @"8.56021285234";
double num = [val doubleValue];
NSLog(@"Number ==> %f",num);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to convert it use

```
 double result = [string doubleValue];
```

For displaying it use %.10f to specify decimal places:

```
NSLog(@"%.10f", result);
```

Comment: How do you know it's only 6 decimal places?Do you use %.10f when you display your result? Can you post your code?

Comment: NSString *value = @"8.44654656565"; double dblValue = [value doubleValue]; NSLog(@"double value %f",dblValue); Getting value 8.446547

Comment: Change your NSLog to NSLog(@"double value %.10f",dblValue); and you will see that the value is not just 6 decimal places. %.10f means show 10 decimal places.

Comment: I want the string to convert in to exact float value. Because i need to use this later in the execution of my code. If i use %.10f i can log the value. But still in my variable its only 6 decimal places.

Comment: No in your variable dblValue is right value it's not rounded value. It's just your nsstring rounded it to display it in nicer way but it hasn't changed the value.

Comment: Yea thanks man. I mistook that the result will be only 6 decimal places. Thanks for understanding me that.

Comment: Also beware that with any floating point number there is always a limit to precision.  You can never store the 'exact' value of a number with a float type beyond a certain number of places.  To give a silly example, if you can find a way to store the exact value of PI in 64 bits you will get the Nobel prize.  Be very careful with == and floats.  It is not a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

```
 NSString *value = @"8.44654656565";
double dblValue = [value doubleValue];
NSLog(@"%.10f",dblValue);
```

Comment: Humm..  Just copy my code and paste that code in to your application and then check it, when i checked here i am getting decimal value properly..

Comment: NSString *value = @"8.44654656565";
double dblValue = [value doubleValue];
NSLog(@"double value  %f",dblValue); Getting value 8.446547

Comment: NSString *value = @"8.44654656565";
    double dblValue = [value doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"%.12f",dblValue); 

Now check it

Comment: I want to get the correct value in variable double dblValue. I want to use this value later in my code.

Comment: Yea thanks man. I mistook that the result will be only 6 decimal places. Thanks for understanding me that.

Answer (score 1):

the double variable have the all information you need, then you format it as text system can display not the whole digits stored in double variable

The Sabareesh code:

```
NSString *value = @"8.44654656565";
double dblValue = [value doubleValue];
NSLog(@"%.12f",dblValue);
```

here *dblValue* have in memory all digits you want and you can use it as you want
*NSLog* here can prove you have enough data - simply because NSLog output it

Answer (score 0):

Please try NSDecimal Number instead of `[string floatValue];`

```
NSDecimalNumber *price1 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"15.99"];
NSDecimalNumber *price2 = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"29.99"];
NSDecimalNumber *coupon = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"5.00"];
NSDecimalNumber *discount = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@".90"];
NSDecimalNumber *numProducts = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"2.0"];

NSDecimalNumber *subtotal = [price1 decimalNumberByAdding:price2];
NSDecimalNumber *afterCoupon = [subtotal decimalNumberBySubtracting:coupon];
NSDecimalNumber *afterDiscount = [afterCoupon decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:discount];
NSDecimalNumber *average = [afterDiscount decimalNumberByDividingBy:numProducts];
NSDecimalNumber *averageSquared = [average decimalNumberByRaisingToPower:2];

NSLog(@"Subtotal: %@", subtotal);                    // 45.98
NSLog(@"After coupon: %@", afterCoupon);           // 40.98
NSLog((@"After discount: %@"), afterDiscount);       // 36.882
NSLog(@"Average price per product: %@", average);    // 18.441
NSLog(@"Average price squared: %@", averageSquared); // 340.070481
```