# different presentation of a float number in DB and webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, floating-point, typeconverter

I have a column named `point` in my database that its type is `float` .But when i try to read the value `point column` it shows me something like this :

```
2.000000000000000e+000
```

While the number is `2` why?I need to show me `2`.

Here is the code that i read the value

```
public class viewpointShow
        {
            public string viewPointId { set; get; }
            public string point { set; get; }
            public string question { set; get; }
            public string JurorUserName { set; get; }
            public string articleId { set; get; }

        }
     List<viewpointShow> q =
                    (dbcontext.tblPoints.Where(i => i.ArtichleId.Value == int.Parse(articleId))
                              .Select(arg => new viewpointShow()
                                  {                             
                                     JurorUserName =arg.JurorUsername,
                                     articleId = arg.ArtichleId.ToString(),
                                     point = arg.Point.ToString(),
                                     question = ReturnQuestionById(arg.QuestionId.Value) 
                                  })).ToList();
            return q;
```

Best regards

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double  and http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: YOu know i just need how can i convert this 2.000000000000000e+000 to 2?

Comment: Why is float at the first place you need to wonder. You can convert it to int using Math functions, or format it using the string.format.

Comment: So how can i do this ?Could you give me an example?

Comment: A float does not have a formatted representation of its own. It all depends on _how_ you convert it to a string. Post the HTML / ASPX.

Comment: Are you sure you want to keep your values as a `float` in your database?

Comment: @SonerGönül so which type do you prefer?

Comment: You know in database the type is float but when i import the table using linqtosql it's changed to double!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify how may decimals you want to see. Possible solutions

```
 //point = arg.Point.ToString()
   point = arg.Point.ToString("0.0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)    // always 1 decimal digit
   point = arg.Point.ToString("#.##", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)   // at most 2
```

Comment: Method tostring has 0 parameter but is invoked with 2 parameteres

Comment: I need to see 2 digit

Comment: Then arg.Point is not a float.

Comment: the type of that in database is float but here i want to show that as a string

Comment: But `arg.Point` is not in the database, it has been read into memory. Find out the type.

Comment: You know in database the type is float but when i import the table using linqtosql it's changed to double!!!!!!

Comment: `double`  has the same `ToString()`s as `float`.