# How much performance gain for changing variables from double to float?

Tags: c++, performance, floating-point, double

I have a program that takes too much time, so I want to optimize my code a bit.

I have used the `double` type for every variable so far. If I change to be of type `float`, will any performance benefits occur?

Comment: I'd expect roughly none, unless your compiler autovectorizes it. Time it and see.

Comment: I imagine this may be somewhat platform-dependent, and that your hardware may play a role here.

Comment: Given the naive nature of the question, I'd say it's quite likely that there are some simple optimizations that will make a real difference in your code's performance and that changing the type isn't one of them.

Comment: The hardware platform, and the amount of time that your application actually spends doing floating point operations will have a lot to do with any performance gain you'll see. Your question provides insufficient info to hazard a guess.

Comment: Stupid question from someone who never deals with much more than application-scope performance: isn't `double` a native type to the processor, so shouldn't it *theoretically* be faster CPU-wise? Again, sorry, that might be a stupid question. I just remember seeing that somewhere and it seems relevant, albeit undetectable or outweighed by other factors.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen: Many common CPUs have hardware support for both IEEE single and double floats.  (This includes x86, PowerPC, ARM...)

Comment: You need to profile your code to find the bottleneck. I doubt this is it.

Comment: First I think you should do program profiling before optimization so as to find out where a lot of time is spent. There are various bottleneck where much time is spent, it could be the data structure, memory, algorithm, data dependency or loop. However to determine exactly these hot spots, you have to use a profiler tool. If it`s double that takes to much CPU time then you could optimize it, but I doubt if it`s data type. You might also consider writing a parallel program.

Comment: One thing changing `double` to `float` will definitely not change, even if `double` is emulated in software, is the time complexity of your program. Removing the tag.

Answer (score 8):

It is impossible to answer this question with any certainty: it will depend on your code and your hardware.  The change will have many possible effects:

- Memory usage will be reduced.
- Cache misses will be fewer.
- CPU instructions will take fewer cycles.
- The compiler may autovectorize, or autovectorize differently.
- Numerical algorithms in your application may no longer converge correctly.

The only way to tell the actual performance difference is to test it yourself.  Sounds like a simple search & replace job.

Comment: Whether any CPU instructions take fewer cycles is platform dependent.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: That's listed under "possible" effects.  Some platforms also have floats and doubles that are the same size, so the memory usage and cache misses are also platform dependent -- not to mention that some hardware has no cache!

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan, although most basic operations take the same time I think `SQRTSS` has always been faster than `SQRTSD`.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely, you will only see noticeable improvements if your code works on a very large block of memory. If you are doing `double` operations on an array of millions of values, you'll cut your memory bandwidth in half by switching to `float`. (I'm assuming you are on a standard architecture where `float` is 32 bits and `double` is 64 bits.)

In terms of reducing load on the CPU, I wouldn't expect to see a significant change. Maybe a small difference for some operations, but probably a few percent at best.

Answer (score 2):

Modern processors execute most FP operations in about the same amount of time for double-precision operands as for single-precision. The only significant speed differences for going down to single-precision are:

- Smaller size, potentially leading to more cache coherence. This is not a significant concern for most algorithms.
- More slots in SIMD (4 versus 2 for SSE without AVX). Obviously only a concern if you're SIMDizing your code.
- Faster division, square roots, and transcendentals. This difference can be significant in some extreme inner loops, but in general your FP ops won't be a big chunk of your total runtime.

Overall, it just isn't likely to be a significant win, except for niche cases. And if you're not familiar with the nature of floating point imprecision and how to reduce it, it's probably best to stick to double-precision and the increased wiggle room it offers you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it if you want better performance, you should do it if you need the [precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double).

[Related Reference](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/38122-what-difference-between-float-double.html)