# Differentiate between float and double

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

```
//assume there is no Print(double dValue)
void Print(unsigned int nValue);
void Print(float fValue);
Print(3.14159);
```

Shouldn't the `Print(3.14159)` match with `Print(float)` ?

Instead of it, this code lead to an ambiguous match

- Is `3.14159` a `double` ?
- How to differentiate between `float` and `double` ?

Comment: What do you mean with ambiguous match? Do you get compiler error or strange behaviors?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is `3.14159` a double ?

Yes, it is.

> How to differentiate between `float` and `double` ?

Use `3.14159f` to make the constant a `float`. Use `3.14159` to make the constant a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

`3.14159` numeric literal is a `double`, not a `float`. C++ has two choices:

- Convert `double` to `unsigned int`, and call the first overload
- Convert `double` to `float`, and call the second overload

Both choices require the same number of conversions, to C++ issues an error.

You can fix this by appending `F` to the end of the literal:

```
Print(3.14159F);
//           ^
```

Now the first choice still requires a `float` to `unsigned int` conversion, while the second choice can proceed without conversion; hence, the second overload "wins".