# Adding float in jsp form type number

Tags: forms, jsp, numbers, el

I am trying to add 0.01 to a variable which has been taken by servlet. I use this variable in jsp form but after adding there is a little problem. This is some part of my code and results.

```
<input type="number" name="bid_price" placeholder="9,99" min="${auction.currently + 0.01}" value="${auction.currently + 0.01}" step="0.01"/>
```

If i use only the variable, the output is correct (e.g. 0.12). When i add 0.01 insead of 0.13 i have as a result 0,129999997317791.

Can you help me to fix that little error?

Comment: How are you passing value from servlet? Can you provide that code?

Comment: You don't need that part of code. What can i say is that ${auction.currently} is a float.

Comment: You can see for your self that you are adding float to 0.01 so resulting value would be `double` not `float`.

Comment: So you tell me that 0.01 is a double? I don't think you really know the difference between double and float. Check this and make t clear to your mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double

Comment: As @NaMaN mentioned. You will get a *Double* if you add *Float* to anything except *BigInteger* in [tag:el]. Refer to: Section 1.7.1 in [Expression Language Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsp-2.1-fr-eval-spec-oth-JSpec/).

Comment: In java if you want compiler to consider 0.01 as `float` than you have to pass `f` like `0.01f` otherwise it will be considered it as double.