# c++ different print behavior between values and variables

Tags: c++, c, printf

I tried the following code on mac, the output is kind of strange to me.

```
float a = 2.225;
float b = 123.235;
printf("round: %.2f %.2f \n", a, b);
printf("round: %.2f %.2f \n", 2.225, 123.235);
```

output:

```
round: 2.22 123.24 
round: 2.23 123.23
```

g++ --version

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

What are the rounding rules in printing? How I can get same printing result in these two situations?
Many thanks.

Comment: I think the difference is between `float`s and `double`s.

Comment: Read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: The problem is not in printing - you are getting different output because you are passing in different input. In the first case, you lose precision the moment you assign `double` values to `float` variables.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double.

Comment: And this is one of those questions where the "C/C++" tag issue strikes. There is nothing in the code that is specifically C++. Should this be re-tagged C? Should the C tag be *added*? Should there be another question asking the same thing under the "C" tag? I give up.

Answer (score 6):

The first `printf()` converts the `float` values to `double` and then prints the results.  Note that the initializations convert the `double` constants to `float`. The second passes the `double` values directly.  You can specify `float` constants with the suffix `F` — but the rules of C still convert those `float` constants to `double` before actually calling `printf()` because of default argument promotion rules.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float a = 2.225;
    float b = 123.235;
    printf("round: %.2f %.2f\n", a, b);
    printf("round: %.2f %.2f\n", 2.225, 123.235);
    printf("round: %.2f %.2f\n", 2.225F, 123.235F);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
round: 2.22 123.24 
round: 2.23 123.23 
round: 2.22 123.24
```

Answer (score 4):

```
2.225
```

That is a literal, of type `double`.

```
float a = 2.225;
```

That is assigning a `double` to a `float` (losing precision, see below).

```
printf( "%.2f", ... );
```

This is printing a `double` (even if you pass a `float` as parameter, due to type promotion), to a precision of two digits after the decimal point.

```
float a = 2.225;
printf( "%.2f", a );
```

This is assigning a `double` to a `float`, then casting it back to a `double` (type promotion), and printing that.

```
printf( "%.2f", 2.225 );
```

This is printing a `double` (*without* the back-and-forth casting).

> What are the rounding rules in printing?

Rounding works as you would expect, but is not your problem here.

The difference in output happens because **your `a` and `b` are `float`, the directly-printed literals aren't**. You happen to have picked values where the loss of precision due to the cast-to-float makes a difference.

> How I can get same printing result in these two situations?

Using `double` consistently.

```
double a = 2.225;
double b = 123.235;
```