# Error converting a integer value to float in c

Tags: c

What I have so far...

---

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <time.h>
        #define ROWS 23
        #define COLS 78


    int main()
    {


        srand(time(NULL));

        int arr[ROWS][COLS];
        int sum = 0, counter1 = 0;
        int k;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < COLS; k++)
            {
                int j = rand() % 10;

                arr[i][k] = j;

                printf("%d", arr[i][k]);

                sum += arr[i][k];

                counter1++;

            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("\n");

        printf("Average = %f\n", float(sum / counter1)); //Not getting exact decimal

        printf("Total numbers = %d\n", counter1);

        printf("Sum of all numbers = %d\n", sum);

        system("pause");
    }
//Guessing the float is not converting as it should
```

---

Output so far....

```
422620351595919054460397694388416319310552973446498175458548095262118564755749
372438759420195802623062987655437952542263796363224469905714526364539742622586
124057899145417666187341286327350448786294141128615529044980269471365598313616
049149926286317172502475330649055931769733144700851693923585818341846097713250
826490802265735183843662244505193942554706854717207204487697516652123593599812
746605634674496934691593122520210519087830081107377133858638184877543092242563
172193699659454833537193985400677695430588428833192355923118027599256651906912
137220359907772463940456613321876957716810615732837946886780325557272201117024
970243922687865367166306388461501128523059854106020838236007732376011146109340
239699228705450117510917862089719947717228921040726908237444581851160698373585
977683407031265082736130690889715335368791599705700863736964292214408266990418
536416318005520152773513475211623892873091447652802755401011207564392549940648
363921632561931849591970346553864295588487844510186065223062209484132581237554
163065518327032754274153946192470922485557045255627009864269391575284952286729
910378772792028085274954077343530447604501744264499511471498074681140863439500
617676961625579079414287810415495010710519733811672377499905168756599387590803
885768234776892368128405809649999684460473809170548180074483476110165080161362
308905170626655925452893089531708914818032726022522429229062646282887593747734
210270837200571461718554091036728525587376768397741678405601722794577171279012
421649999013761899858408492974830996084297030747093760611147983343593657910519
461743953198670501367758536958306703445033922711724727706025545309033925365602
635580784707723652610577238350330553362131582484629421787969994692199573628406
521293251392156351047950677006976709658442231650692040031419198232429972214834

Average = 4.000000

Total numbers = 1794

Sum of all numbers = 8054

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `float(sum / counter1)` --> `(float)sum / counter1`

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help :) I feel dumb not trying that lol.

Comment: Curious: Why does code use `float` rather than `double`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double

Answer (score 0):

You can format the number to 2 decimal place by placing ".2f" :

```
printf("Average = %.2f\n", float(sum) / float(counter1));
```

Comment: Whatever language the expression `float(sum) / float(counter1)` might have arisen from, it is not C.

Answer (score 0):

`float(sum / counter1)` --> `(float)sum / counter1`
                    – BLUEPIXY