# double comparison is not working exactly

Tags: c, double, precision

I have some code that I will simplify to this:

```
double x;
double y;
double z;
.
.

while (x + y != z)
    do stuff;
```

The problem is that x + y is very close to z but somewhere in my code it looses precision and so is x + y is a bit off. I have tried things like:

`while (x + y + 0.0001 > z && x + y - 0.0001 < z)` but I wanna do something more general. Is there some notation / function like this:

`while (x + y != nextdouble(z) && x + y != prevdouble(z) && x + y != z)`

where `nextdouble()` would give the smallest possible double greater than the parameter.

Comment: Have a look at [**Difference between float and double**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/difference-between-float-and-double) and specifically the link in the 2nd answer.

Comment: It's best not to compare floating point values for equality. If you absolutely *must*, using a range **is** the way to go.

Comment: It does not necessary have to be "the next closest number". There is no easy and straightforward answer for the question you ask. You need to learn a bit of theory of numeric calculations.

Comment: `nextafter()`/`nexttoward()`

Comment: Maybe you should use `static inline double reldiff(double x, double y)
{
    return fabs(x - y) / fmax(fabs(x), fabs(y));
}` and test `if (reldiff(x + y, z) < 1E-8)` or some other similar small fraction.