# Missing decimal ArduinoJson

Tags: json, string, arduino, decimal

I'm using this code:

```
const size_t bufferSize = JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(2) + 2*JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(3) + JSON_OBJECT_SIZE(7);
DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(bufferSize);
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.createObject();
JsonObject& loc = root.createNestedObject("loc");
loc["lat"] = 45.123456;
loc["lng"] = 54.654321;
```

And I'm getting in the output this:

```
{"loc":{"lat":45.12346,"lng":54.65432}}
```

But when I change values to strings ("xx.xxxxxx"), it works normally, just giving me a string instead of a double. Why am I missing that 5 and 1?

Comment: Because of the limited floating point precision.

Comment: How to fix it, what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **ARDUINOJSON_USE_DOUBLE** configuration parameter to allow ArduinoJson to use ***double*** instead of ***float*** type.

```
#if ARDUINOJSON_USE_DOUBLE
typedef double Float;
#else
typedef float Float;
#endif
```

If needed you can get more details about float vs double : [What is the difference between float and double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/what-is-the-difference-between-float-and-double)