# C++ different output in double and float

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, precision

I have a sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  float a = 33.30;

  double b = 33.30;

  char a1[1024];
  char b1[1024];

  sprintf(a1, "%0.6f", a);
  sprintf(b1, "%0.6lf", b);

  cout << a1 << endl;
  cout << b1 << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
33.299999
33.300000
```

I am getting correct result for double and incorrect for float.
 I am unable to understand this behavior. 
 Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264127/correct-format-specifier-for-double-in-printf

there is not correct format for float, hence there is conversion from float to double and you get this kind of value

Comment: `double` has more precision than `float`

Comment: `float` has a 23 bit mantissa, equivalent to 6.92 decimal digits of precision; there you are printing 8, it's clear that you'll see the rounding error implicit in the decimal conversion. `double` instead has a 52 bit mantissa - the equivalent of 15.65 decimal digits -, so an 8 significant digits rounding holds plenty well.

Answer (score 2):

33.3 has no exact bounded binary representation, so converting it to `float` or `double` incurs in rounding.

`float` has a 23 bit mantissa, equivalent to 6.92 decimal digits of precision; there you are asking to print 8 digits, which are more than the available precision, and thus will show the effect or the rounding.

`double` instead has a 52 bit mantissa, which is equivalent to 15.65 decimal digits; the 8 significant digits print holds well, as you are still printing good digits, unaffected by the rounding.

---

To make an easier to digest example in our beloved base 10: imagine you had a decimal data type with 15 digits of precision, and you want to store 1/3 in it. The best you can do is to store 0.333333333333333; them you copy it into a data type with 6 digits of precision: it becomes 0.333333.

Now, if you print the first value with 8 decimal digits you get 0.33333333, while for the second one you have 0.33333300 - as you already lost the other digits in the conversion.

That is what is happening here, but with binary floating point instead of decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good answer to the difference of float vs. double.

[What is the difference between float and double?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386772/what-is-the-difference-between-float-and-double)

By default, any magic number (as 33.30 in your program) is processed as double. when you do `float a = 33.30;`, an error occurred.

Comment: @Hamed, Thanks, I have revised it.