# C# Converting Double to Float Loses So Much Precision Why?

Tags: c#, floating-point

When I'm debugging my program using Visual Studio;

When I convert a double variable "91.151497095188446" to a float by using

```
(float)double_variable
```

I see resulting float variable is "91.1515".

Why I'm losing so much precision? Do I need to use another data type?

Comment: Well yes, if you want more than 7 significant digits of precision, you need a different data type. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single?view=netframework-4.7.2): "A Single value has up to 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally." (Note that although you're only seeing 6 digits, that's because the value is 91.15150 to 7 significant digits.) Fundamentally, if you don't want to lose precision, don't use a less precise type.

Comment: you can try Decimal type if losing precision is critical (e.g. financial calculations)

Comment: Why do you expect it not to lose precision? Why are you considering using `float` at all - why not keep using `double`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# and many other languages use [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) as a specification for their floating-point data types. Floating-point numbers are expressed as a significand and an exponent, similar to how a decimal number, in scientific notation, is expressed as

```
1.234567890 x 10^12
     ^          ^
  mantissa   exponent
```

I won't go into the details (the Wikipedia article goes into that better than I can), but IEEE 754 [specifies that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Basic_and_interchange_formats):

- for a 32-bit floating point number, such as the C# [`float`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/float) data type, has 24 bits of precision for the significand, and 8 bits for the exponent.
- for a 64-bit floating point number, such as the C# [`double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double) data type, has 53 bits of precision for the significand, and 11 bits for the exponent.

Because a `float` only has 24 *bits* of precision, it can only express 7-8 *digits* of precision. Conversely, a `double` has 53 *bits* of precision so has about 15-16 *digits* of precision.

As has been said in the comments, if you don't want to lose precision, don't go from a `double` (64 bits in total) to a `float` (32 bits in total). Depending on your application, you could perhaps use the [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal) data type which has 28-29 decimal digits of precision - but will come with penalties because (a) calculations involving it are slower than for `double` or `float`, and (b) it's typically far less supported by external libraries.

---

Note that you're talking about `91.15149709518846` which will actually be interpreted as `91.1514970951884` by the compiler - see, for example, [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jCxHFp):

```
double value = 91.151497095188446;
Console.WriteLine(value);
// prints 91.1514970951884
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find detailed explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386882/10863059

Basically, float takes smaller memory space (4 bytes) when compared to double (8 bytes), but that's just one part of the story.

Answer (score 0):

> Floating-point types store fractional parts as inverse powers of two. For this reason, they
> can only represent exact values such as 10, 10.25, 10.5, and so on. Other numbers,
> such as 1.23 or 19.99, cannot be represented exactly and are only an approximation.
> Even if double has 15 decimal digits of precision, as compared to only 7 for float,
> precision loss starts to accumulate when performing repeated calculations.

> This makes double and float difficult or even inappropriate to use in certain types of
> applications, such as financial applications, where precision is key. For this purpose, the
> decimal type is provided

Reference : Learn C# Programming, A guide to building a solid foundation in C# language
for writing efficient programs By **Marius Bancila,
Raffaele Rialdi,
Ankit Sharma**